# How to create a variable length scrollview with choose able indices

Tags: android, xml

I am attempting to create a scrollview that is variable length that has X amount of objects. These are currently set up as Linear layouts that are just names "item0", etc... I am attempting to make this list variable in size, so that once a item is chosen it can move to the next step and be removed from the list. this is what i have currently. This is definitly not the correct way to do this and i am hoping someone could shed some light on how to correctly continue.
Thank you
-Steven

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Description">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lin1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="34dp"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sample" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="item0"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lin2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="34dp"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sample" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="item1"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lin3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="34dp"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sample" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="item2"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lin4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="34dp"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sample" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="item04"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why not a ListView?

Comment: You need to use RecyclerView (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). This is the most productive solution.

Comment: Awesome thank you, ill look into this!